# Do I need a comma before 'I guess' in this sentence?

Tags: commas

> There's always a trade-off I guess.

The sentence seems incorrect whether I add one or not; I might just have to re-word it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest adding a comma since you can switch the two clauses.

From:

> There's always a trade-off, I guess.

When clauses are switched:

> I guess there's always a trade-off.

Comment: There isn't a pause when the clauses are switched, but would it still be correct if I decided to add a comma in anyway?

Comment: @Sq.Ima: No. It would be *completely* wrong to include a comma if you *start* the utterance with ***I guess*** (which is the default "natural" sequence for English). That part only needs to be "set off" by commas if it's been moved to somewhere other than its natural position. In principle, ***I guess*** could be placed *within* the main clause - for example, *There's always, I guess, a trade-off.* In which case it needs commas *before **and** after* (because it's an optional *parenthetical* clause).

Comment: What if I replace the comma with a semi-colon & put I guess at the end of the sentence?

Comment: @Sq.Ima Don't use a semicolon if you would find a period inappropriate. Would you write just *I guess* as a sentence on its own? It doesn't go against syntax—but it would sound very strange in this particular example.